# Reading data form Elasticsearch into Flink aggregation?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-storm, flink-streaming, trident

I'm trying to update documents in Elasticsearch using Kafka messages (as a StreamSource). Writing to Elasticsearch in bulks using windows and the Elasticsearch connector as a sink is fine, however, we need to update existing data in the documents and read that in a bulk-performant manner (not for every tuple but for e.g. the whole window after a `byKey()` split that we want to aggregate over)

We are using Storm Trident right now which is performing bulk reads before a [`persistentAggregate`](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.2/Trident-state.html) and writes the updated aggregations back after, minimizing interaction with the backend. I just can't find something similar in Flink - any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about running two window call on stream -

`window1` - To bulk read from elasticsearch

`window2` - To bulk into elasticsearch.

```
streamData
  .window1(bulkRead and update/join)
  .processFunction(...)
  .window2(BulkPush)
```

- You can use any suitable method for bulk-read like `Storm Trident`.
- use BulkProcessor in window2 [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This needs loading for EVERY window1 as opposed to having an internal cache and just loading the keys that are not already present - but you are right in that I probably will have to load, update and save everything in in the processFunction - it just seems very manual and non-performant wrt database access and bulk-reading/writing. Thanks for the hint though!